# how to add and customize items in menu/nav bar in header

Tags: magento-2.1, menu, topmenu

**I am customizing the ultimo theme.**

In the top menu or the user menu there are five links like:

```
accounts
wishlist
signin
signup
cart
```

**I want to change these LINKS and also I want to add more links like pages.** But i am unable to do so.

I am very new to magento and finding very difficult to customize it.  i am using magento 2.1

**P.S** i dont know how it is off topic please leave a comment in case of negative voting. Thanks!

Comment: If you need Magento 2.1, you don't have to put the `Magento 1.9` tag

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: @ManojDeswal i am checking it. Let me check

Comment: which demo of theme you are using ?

Comment: demo 1 we are using.

Comment: okay , you want some custom links like "about us" page ?

Comment: I want to remove signin and signup page because account is already using them. I want to add search as an icon only.  Moreover the main menu which includes home i want to change it to show more links. I cannot see how to change these.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65528/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-tech-geek).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) To remove sign up and sign in links**  edit your default.xml code at below location.

```
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Add these lines of code

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">

    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for sign up Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->

</referenceBlock>
```

**2) Add more links with account links** enable this block **Custom Top Links (to replace Magento's default Top Links)**

```
Go to Admin > Content > Blocks >  Custom Top Links (to replace Magento's default Top Links) > Enable
```

Place your custom links in this block

**3) Add custom links in main menu with Home** these links come at right side by defaul

**Go to Blocks** and edit this block "**Main menu - custom links**" add your custom links for main menu here.

see below picture , I put some custom links at both place and removed the links which you wanted to remove

[image]

**4) Placing custom links next to Home Link**

For this you can use this simple method of placing custom links:

- Create a block and place your content in this block ,

  - Note: This is block you need to assign in category
- Create a **sub category to root category**

  - i.e Name it **My Test Link**
  - Set **"yes"** to include in menu and enable category
  - In **content section** > Add CMS Block > Select your block
  - Display Setting > Display mode > Static Blocks only
  - Save the category and then **Drag it to set the order**, Like **I dragged it to first position to show just after home link**

[image]

All done !

Keep cache disabled / flush your cache

Comment: hi manoj i am trying this and let you know if i get any problem.

Comment: I hope you will get it done easily , if not then I am here

Comment: sure. it will take some time to drive to office

Comment: sorry for late answer. In your answer number 3. i have opened this but it is including the link with about us. What i want to add the links with home, like what's new, women and men.

Comment: Okay, I reply for this tomorrow after checking  , as currently  I am not in front of my office system . I hope other worked for you ?

Comment: yeah everything is working fine.  it will be great if you just give me a hint. or tomorrow will be cool. Thank you for so far

Comment: you can add a category to menu and assign blocks to category for displaying that as a page , or align left your custom links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65575/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-tech-geek).

Comment: sorry for late answer. Let me try this . I am doing this now.

Comment: okay, I hope this should work for you

Comment: thank you for your time and sorry for replying late. Yeah working fine i am doing drop down in the menu links. Cheers!

Comment: here are other answers related to your theme https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193194/i-want-to-change-a-product-page-design-and-reposition-some-elements    ,

Comment: i have a question. regarding this i want to change the cart like i want to change the text to bag and hide the cart icon . But in custom i dont think there is any option available

Comment: hide the cart icon and change text cart to bag, right ? well I ll try to find out the solution ..meanwhile you can post query for this if someone else know ..can help you

Comment: sure manoj! yeah i will do it. i thought it is related to this thread so i posted here

Comment: that comes via checkout module not from header ... I am finding it...hope will get it soon for you

Comment: not only cart but i want to actually completely edit it search and accounts too.

Comment: post in small threads... so question should not too broad , otherwise your question can be closed by community

Comment: okay sure manoj!

Answer (score 2):

I use the Ultimo Theme on a Magento 1.9 instance, but the method is the same for 2.1.

In the user guide, there is a section (starting on page 80) that covers built-in blocks.  In the sub-section `6.2.3 List of built-in static blocks and containers`, you will find that the block-identifier you are looking for is `block_nav_links`, and if you want to add content in a dropdown, it is `block_nav_dropdown`.

There is a link in that section to `12.3.1 Custom links inside a static block` that shows an example of what the html should look like inside your block with an identifier of `block_nav_link`:

```
<li class="nav-item level0 level-top right">
    <a class="level-top" href="{{store direct_url='about-magento-demo-store'}}">
        <span>Sample Internal Link</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item level0 level-top right">
    <a class="level-top" href="http://infortis-themes.com/">
        <span>Sample External Link</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: hi thank for you response let me view this and get back to you. May be i have a few questions regarding this let me test this .\

Comment: sorry i have not understand from the documents. I mean these menu bars are already a block and i have to add more block in it ?

Comment: I didn't realize when I wrote this answer that you were using demo-content.  In that case, there should be a block with an identifier `block_nav_links` that you can edit with code similar to my example.  There should also be a block with an identifier of `block_nav_dropdown` that you can edit if you want to include dropdown-content.  You can remove either of them by disabling the block(s).