# I want to change a product page design and reposition some elements

Tags: magento2

I want to change the representation of product page like add some new things, reviews at the end of the page and reposition some elements. In which and where in files, I have to change. I am finding all given answers confusing.

Comment: Have you created a new theme? I can help will start with moving reviews?

Comment: @harri  I am using a new theme ultimo.  And your help will be highly appreciated bro

Comment: are you using theme  demo  and please provide more details , which element s you want to place where ...etc

Comment: @ManojDeswal  no I have purchased . And I want to move customer reviews at the end of page , change button color etc .

Comment: currently reviews coming next to more information and you want them in the end of page not in the tab , right ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal yes coming in tab

Comment: also , please share your web url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65582/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-learner).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send customer reviews in the end of page edit your **catalog_product_view.xml** at below location

```
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

And add this line of code there

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/>
```

Keep cache disable or flush your cache.

Comment: can you come in chat for few minutes ? please

Comment: Where to add this code as there are more then 100 lines

Comment: in last before  these tags "</body>
</page>"

Comment: can I have 5 minutes ?

Comment: hello , how can I help ?

Comment: can you guide on this ?   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196494/side-menu-not-appearing-on-sub-categories    @Manoj Deswal

Comment: I will check it when I ll come to workstation