# Side menu not appearing on sub categories

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I am using magento 2.1.8  and I have made a category named `shop`  on shop page its showing all subcategories on left side . like  `brushes, tube` etc  now when I click on `brush` it goes to all product added to brushes. but there is no category panel on left side . Can I have same panel (which is in shop category panel) on brush aswell ?

Comment: Is your category brushes an anchor?

Comment: I checked by doing on and off but no result on sub categories page. @Nikolas

Comment: when you select brushes , it will show product from this category and on left it will show only selected category - default in luma

Comment: But in  when I go to brushes I shows nothing on left side. I want to show all products of   SHOP category in brushes left side @ManojDeswal

Comment: its little tough to understand how your left panel behaving , and I think you are on local